# Get the color of the fist Heikin Ashi Bar of the day

Tags: pine-script

I am plotting the Heikin Ashi 60 M data series at the bottom of my 60 M chart :

[image: Chart]

I would like to get the color of the first Heikin Ashi bar of the day in order to use it to trigger an entry.

I would appreciate some help since I am stuck and can't find the way to do it. Thank in advance.

Hereafter my code :

```
// === Heikin Ashi START
// --- First Bar
isFirstBar = ta.change(time("60"))
// --- plots
bullColor       = input.color(#00E600, title="Bull Color", group="Heikin Ashi")
bearColor       = input.color(#FF0000, title="Bear Color", group="Heikin Ashi")
// --- Timeframes
timeframe      = input.timeframe("60", '60', group="Heikin Ashi")
// --- Functions
calculateHeikinColor(timeframe) =>
    ha_t                = ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid)
    ha_open             = request.security(ha_t, str.tostring(timeframe),open)
    ha_close            = request.security(ha_t, str.tostring(timeframe),close)

    col = ha_close > ha_open ? bullColor : bearColor

longEntry = calculateHeikinColor(timeframe) == bullColor
shortEntry = calculateHeikinColor(timeframe) == bearColor

plotshape(longEntry and isFirstBar, title='Long', style=shape.circle, location=location.bottom, color=color.green, size=size.auto)
plotshape(shortEntry and isFirstBar, title='Short', style=shape.circle, location=location.bottom, color=color.red, size=size.auto)
```

// --- END

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isFirstBar = ta.change(time("60"))` this will return `true` every hour. You want to change this to `"D"`.

Also, you might want to store that information in a `var` variable in order to store it somewhere until the next day starts.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

is_green = (close > open)
is_green_ha = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, is_green)

is_new_day = ta.change(time("D"))
bgcolor(is_new_day ? color.new(color.blue, 85) : na)

var first_ha_was_green = false
first_ha_was_green := is_new_day ? is_green_ha : first_ha_was_green

plotchar(first_ha_was_green, "first_ha_was_green", "")
```

Comment: Understood, Works as expected. Appreciated